# A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 4 (near " date: 2021-06-27") in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to fetch the data from some HTML page and show them into a view by following this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/12?page=2
Here i using YAML front matter for fetch data from my-forth-post.html

this is my model Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Post
{
    public $title;
    public $excerpt;
    public $date;
    public $body;
    public $slug;

    public function __construct($title,$excerpt,$date,$body,$slug){
        $this -> title = $title;
        $this -> excerpt = $excerpt;
        $this -> date = $date;
        $this -> body = $body;
        $this -> slug = $slug;
    }

    public static function all(){
        $files = File::files(resource_path("posts/"));

        return array_map(function ($file){
            return $file->getContents();
        },$files);
    }
    public static function find($slug)
    {
        if (!file_exists($path = resource_path("posts/{$slug}.html"))) {
            throw new ModelNotFoundException();
        }

        return cache()->remember("posts.{$slug}", 1200, function () use ($path) {
            return file_get_contents($path);
        });
    }
}
```

This is web.php

```
<?php

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter;


Route::get('/', function () {
    $files = File::files(resource_path("posts"));

    $posts = array_map(function($file){
        $document = YamlFrontMatter::parseFile($file);

        return new Post(
            $document ->title,
            $document ->excerpt,
            $document ->date,
            $document ->body(),
            $document -> slug
       );
    },$files);
    
    return view('posts',[
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
});

Route::get('post/{post}',function($slug){
    $post = Post::find($slug);
    return view('post',[
        'post' => $post
    ]);
})->where('post','[A-z_/-]+');
```

This is my-forth-post.html

```
---
title: This is forth page
slug: my-forth-post
excerpt: fasdlkfjsdjk
date: 2021-06-30
---
<p>
    What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book it has?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

### remove space from

### title: This is forth page
slug: my-forth-post
excerpt: fasdlkfjsdjk
date: 2021-06-30